# Someone explain {{> player}} to me

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

Working through the meteor examples and mostly getting the hang of everything. I'm also new to handlebars and just trying to wrap my head around things. In the leaderboard example in meteor. What is happening in this part of the code:

> ```
> <div class="leaderboard">
>    {{#each players}}
>     {{> player}}
>    {{/each}}
> </div>
> ```

More specifically i'm confused by {{>player}}. Why can't I just do {{player}}? What is {{>player}} doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{> player }}` calls for the [partial](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/#partials) named `player`. As mentioned in this [site](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers)

> Partials come in handy when you have a chunk of a Handlebars.js
>   template that you need to use in a few different contexts.

While `{{player}}` is a placeholder for the value that you'll pass to the template to be rendered.

I created a [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/OnesimusUnbound/BDMCw/1/) in jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok looking at the code for awhile I think its starting to click. So player inherits the context of players? So for example it can call {{name}} because its a partial? Not having it as a partial does not give it access to {{name}} or {{score}}? Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you post that data you're trying to render and the content of the partial?

Comment: See sample code. For the other other scenario you're referring to `not having partial`, may you post a sample?

Comment: Was just thinking out loud. So {{> player}} represents a template while {{players}} calls the function. So calling {{player}} does nothing because there is no function defined for it yet. Here is the code [link](https://github.com/aconfino/leaderboard) *Not me, just someone on github*

Comment: Hmm, `{{> player }}` appears to be a `meteor` extension on the handlebar (http://docs.meteor.com/#templates). As for your link, it appears to be part of the meteor's example (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/leaderboard)

Answer (score 2):

The {{> player}} code calls a nested template.
You can access the player values generated by the #each iteration.
It is useful to keep your code organized.